# How to analyze new sources using dartanalyzer AnalysisContext?

Tags: dart

For code-generation purpose, I would like to analyze the sources of a package.

I already possess an AnalysisContext thanks to source_gen, but it hasn't computed to sources for the package I want to.

Is there any way to tell that context to compute new sources? Or do I have to use a new context?

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen/issues/273

Comment: No it's unrelated. This is not a bug, I'm simply deviating from the usual path. It's normal for the analyser to not have loaded that package yet